grails 6.2 and spring framework 6
I am working with a grails application (6.2.0) that is currently configured to use Spring Framework 5.3.39. I would like to upgrade to 6.1.14. Has anyone done this successfully? (or upgraded to any version of spring 6?) It appears that the most recent version of grails is not compatible with spring 6 but I'm wondering if there is a work around. (It is currently deployed in tomcat9 but we would upgrade to tomcat10 for spring 6).

I doubt it would work as Spring 5 is JavaEE compatible and Spring 6 is JakartaEE compatible. The components in Grails would follow the same approach as it is bound to certain Spring Boot versions, in this case 2.7.
